# Calculated field in Jira

Tags: java, jira

I'm writing a plug-in for Jira and I need to add custom calculated column to issue navigator. That's column should show last comment to issue. But in issue navigator values in this column are something like "ClassName@123456", not comment's body. What should I do to return comment's body to this column?

Code so far:

```
public class LastCommentField extends CalculatedCFType {
    private CommentManager commentManager = null;

    public LastCommentField(CommentManager commentManager) {
        this.commentManager=commentManager;
    }

    public Object getValueFromIssue(CustomField field, Issue issue) {
        Comment lastComment=null;
        List<Comment> comments = commentManager.getComments(issue);
        if(comments != null && !comments.isEmpty()) {
            lastComment = (Comment)comments.get(comments.size() - 1);
        }   
        return lastComment;
    }

    public String getStringFromSingularObject (Object object) {
        return object.toString();
    }

    public Object getSingularObjectFromString(String value) {
        return value;       
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should show a code example of what you have done already

Comment: Have you tried asking on https://answers.atlassian.com/ ? Atlassian has a big community which unfortunately does not hang on stackoverflow a lot. You can also get direct developer support there - from JIRA's own devs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality already exists in at least two plugins, e.g. https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/net.customware.jira.utils.customware-jira-utilities

But in the code above, the singular object being used is a Comment object as documented at http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/4.4/com/atlassian/jira/issue/comments/Comment.html
but you probably just want a String, so try

return lastComment.getBody();

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't know JIRA from the coding side of things, but from the Java side, that sounds a hell of a lot like the object behind the column doesn't have `ToString()` overriden. What you are seeing is the name of the class followed by the address in memory.

If you could show us the code behind the column, I might be able to make a little more sense of it.